# Redirect audio from a specific process to a specific audio device or even channel

Tags: alsa, pulseaudio

How can I redirect the audio generated by a process (or by a group of processes knowing the parent's process ID) to PulseAudio and then to a specific audio hardware (or even to a specific channel)?

What should be the minimal PulseAudio configuration?

I have a Python script generating sinusoid and I want to redirect that sound to my subwoofer only (I have 5.1 audio system) for example. I want to capture every sound generated by that process only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's several questions. :-)

1a) In general, applications that produce sound for Pulseaudio identify themselves to the Pulseaudio server by some name, and identifying them with that name, you can redirect the audio stream to specific hardware sinks.

1b) If your processes produce sound by writing in some format to `stdout` or similar, you can pipe it to `paplay`, and then process it like it came from a Pulseaudio application. Use the `-n` option to give it a client name specific to your process (like `paplay -n "sinusoid generator"`).

1c) If your processes produce sound using ALSA, choose `pulse` as default device in your `.asoundrc`:

```
pcm.!default pulse
ctl.!default pulse
```

This will add a compatibility layer and forward the sound to Pulseaudio, where it again will show up as an application with a specific name.

1d) If your processes produce sound in a different way, you have to tell us more specifics.

2a) You can redirect Pulseaudio sound output from an application to a specific sink using the `pavucontrol` GUI. The standard Pulseaudio setup includes a module which remembers which applications use which sinks, and restores those assignments automatically when the application starts next time. So you need to do that only once.

2b) You also do that from the commandline, using `pacmd move-sink-input`, after using other `pacmd` together with `grep` to get the required names. Just using the GUI is simpler, though.

3a) You can only move complete audio streams, not channels. However, you can play several streams at once on one sink, so if your sinusoid generator produces 5.1 audio with the sinusoid only on the subwoofer channels, that's where it will play, and you can play other sounds on your 5.1 audio system at the same time.

3b) If you are using `paplay` (s.a.), you can use `--channels` and `--channel-map` to make sure your sinusoid plays on the subwoofer channel. See `man paplay` for details.

3c) If neither of the above works for you, you can create an extra (virtual) sink atop the hardware sink, and remap the channels (e.g. single mono sink input -> subwoofer channel output).

4) The standard Pulseaudio configuration used by most distros should be sufficient. Making it more minimal by identifying and removing modules and packages that won't be used is possible, but quite a bit of work (and of course it depends on your distro).

Comment: I believe my case is 1d) Ultimately I plan to use Amazon Alexa and I want to capture its output audio stream, route it through PulseAudio and send it via RTP protocol (or via some custom ALSA virtual soundcard kernel module) through the network to some "dummy device" based on ESP32.And on the opposite direction too - the "dummy device" will have microphone and will send the audio to the same custom ALSA driver through the PulseAudio server to same(or different) instance of Amazon Alexa. Does anybody know how Amazon Alexa streams and captures the audio(1a-1d),I'm planning to use the Python API?

Comment: I don't have Amazon Alexa, but once you install and run it, it should be easy to find out if it does (a) or (c). I don't think it does (b) or (d). Setting up all sorts of streaming connections and loopbacks is no problem in Pulseaudio, but of course each redirection adds delay. RTP sources and sinks for Pulseaudio exist.